# send id to another form when button clicked and change value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to send the id to another page then select the data by that id from the other page so it works but for only 1 data like if i have server 1 and server 2  server 1 will work but server 2 wont work can any one tell me what is the problem here is my codes

> PHP

```
<?php
$get = $data->show(" SELECT * FROM servers where film_name='avengers' ");
foreach ($get as $row) {
 $id=$row['server_id'];
 $name=$row['server_name'];
 $link=$row['link'];
 $movie=$row['film_name'];
?>
<button type="button" id="btn"  value="<?php echo $id ?>" class="btn btn-warning"><?php echo "$name"; ?></button> 
<?php } ?>
```

> ajax

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){

        $('#btn').click(function (){

var serverid = $('#btn').val();


$.ajax({
    url:"../../control/operation/view_movie.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{serverid:serverid},
    success:function(data)
    {
$("#show").html(data);
    }
});

        });
    });
</script>
```

> viewmovie page

```
    <?php

    $id=$_POST['serverid'];
    $getuser = $data->getdata("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE server_id='$id'");
    $link=$getuser['link'];
    $name=$getuser['film_name'];

     ?>
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<?php echo $link ?>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

it is not like when i load the first one the other wont load even if i didnt load the first one the others wont work 
thanks for helping 
     [image: img for detail]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` is a number and you are identifying it as a string in the query.

So change this: `$getuser = $data->getdata("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE server_id='$id'");`

To this: `$getuser = $data->getdata("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE server_id=$id");`

just remove the quotations (' ').

---

Solution 2

For the button use this:

`<button type="button" value="<?php echo $id ?>" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="getmovie(<?php echo $id ?>)"><?php echo "$name"; ?></button>`

where `onclick="getmovie(<?php echo $id ?>)"` is the funtion to view the movie and we are sending the id as parameter.
And the ajax is as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getmovie(serverid){
        $.ajax({
        url:"../../control/operation/view_movie.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{serverid:serverid},
        success:function(data)
            {
                $("#show").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: that did not work either :( the other 2 buttons still dont work

Comment: Do all the buttons have same id value?

Comment: yes all the button id must be `btn` because i am looping them

Comment: so that is the problem you can't have same id for all it will confuse the jquery code by what button to choose, in your case it is always choosing the first one.

Comment: how can i fix that ? i am new to ajax and jqury i tried all i can can you send me something that can be help for my problem ?

Comment: Try the 2nd solution

Comment: even second one did not work but thanks you told me what is my problem i  will try to search more

Comment: try to alert(serverid) in the getmovie function to make sure you are getting it right. And have you included the jquery library?

Comment: yes i did included it 
in your second one i dont even get any alerts like the button did not even been clicked no response at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213195/discussion-between-ibrahim-and-mhamad-aras).

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that required params are available on the second page.

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['serverid'])){
    $id=$_POST['serverid'];
    $getuser = $data->getdata("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE server_id='$id'");
    $link=$getuser['link'];
    $name=$getuser['film_name'];
?>
     <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<?php echo $link ?>" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<?php }else{
?>
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" allowfullscreen> No data</iframe>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: my first attempt i did that but did not work that is why i removed it but still did not work

Comment: Instead of iframe return some div element to show data not avaliable

Comment: even with a normal text the only one works is the first one i mean with out the php code